# Find control of repeater nested in datalist on repeater item command

Tags: repeater, datalist

In my code repeater is nested in datalistdatalist contains checkboxes and radiobutton
i want to do database operation on checkchanged of checkboxes,so i had written this operation on repeater itemcomand. Here I am not able to find control of repeater.so please guide me how to find control of repeater.

My design is like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DatalistQues" runat="server" DataKeyField="QuestionID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataListText_SelectedIndexChanged"
Width="100%" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="width: 13%">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CssClass="ppppp">
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<% #Eval("Image")%>' Height="60px"
Width="65px" />
</asp:LinkButton>
</td>
<td style="width: 87%">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton7" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CssClass="ppppp">
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("name")%>'></asp:Label>
</asp:LinkButton>
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 13%">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 87%; white-space: pre-line">
            <asp:Label ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("Question")%>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 13%">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 87%">
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

                function fnCheckUnCheck(objId) {
                    var grd = document.getElementById("TabContainer1_TabPanel2_DatalistQues");
                    alert(grd);
                    //Collect A
                    var rdoArray = grd.getElementsByTagName("input");
                    alert(rdoArray);
                    for (i = 0; i <= rdoArray.length - 1; i++) {
                        if (rdoArray[i].type == 'radio') {
                            if (rdoArray[i].id != objId) {
                                rdoArray[i].checked = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }  
            </script>
            <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterQues" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table style="border: none">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 100px">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton23" runat="server" CommandName="radiob">
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" onclick="fnCheckUnCheck(this.id);" /></asp:LinkButton><asp:LinkButton
                                        ID="LinkButton24" runat="server" CommandName="checkb">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QOption") %>' /></asp:LinkButton>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 100px">
                                <asp:Label ID="empname" Text='<%#Eval("QOption") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Firstly, for DataBinding controls like DataList, Repeater etc., only the controls contained in the Templates (ItemTemplate, HeaderTemplate etc.,) gets rendered. Not the Repeater or DataList as a whole.

Comment: If you have a closer look at the HTML rendered on the page (using the Developer Tools) you will get a better understanding on what gets rendered and the pattern in which the controls gets the IDs assigned.

Comment: I want to find control on repeater itemcomand

Comment: protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {

Comment: repeater id is coming like repeater_0 for 1st repeater,repeater_1 for 2nd and so on. bt i want to get id of repeater where checkbox is checked

Comment: I hope you are talking about the server event. Then e.Item on the RepeaterCommandEventArgs parameter will give you the RepeaterItem from where you will be able to find control whether it be the RadioButton1 or CheckBox1 or empname etc., which are contained in the  ItemTemplate of your Repeater control

Comment: from e.item i am able to find control of radio button, but how to find control of repeater

Comment: Posted as an answer. Please see if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
((Repeater)e.Item.Parent).ID // this gives the ID as specified on the aspx page
```

If you need Unique ID, you have to use this

```
((Repeater)e.Item.Parent).ClientID
```

Comment: This is giving Id of repeater but for doing operation I need this value as repeater

Comment: (Repeater)e.Item.Parent is the Repeater object that you are looking for. To get the ID, you can use the above lines of code. If not any of these, What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

On Item command of Repeater you will have to first find the naming container of sender

it will return you datalist item.

then in returned list item you will have to find the repeater of that particular data list itme
once you will find the repeater you can easily find the controls of the item of repeater

Comment: finding naming container through DataListItem myCurrentItem = DatalistQues.SelectedItem; return null